# Голосование без авторизации

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, голоса-против, голоса-за

При попытке голосования на сообщениях без авторизации на сайте, появляется баннер:

> [image: Спасибо за отзыв]

[Sign up or log in](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/98376638?key=495dd1fb3540a846ab4895b7d2adafb6) я уже перевёл (ждём подкачки transifex).
Но тут есть и другие проблемы:

- Текст описания длиннее, чем в оригинале, из-за этого выравнивание кажется кривым (надо либо урезать текст, либо дорабатывать форматирование этого окна).
- "Регистрация" смешивается с "Зарегистрироваться" (надо бы выбрать что-то одно).
- ["е-мейл"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/62653007?qt=%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB) я бы оформил как "e-mail".

Comment: а если убрать *или* и сделать "Войти/Регистрация" ?

Comment: @Alex это что-то улучшит? По-моему, с этим никаких проблем нет.

Comment: @Alex так вертикального зазора всё равно не появится. И текст по-прежнему будет сливаться.

Comment: я подумал, что не помещается "Зарегистрируйтесь или войдите" :)

Comment: @Alex это, кстати, тоже вопрос. Будет видно после обновления.

Comment: по поводу *Текст описания длиннее, чем в оригинале* - можно попробовать сократить текст, например так *Этот сайт бесплатен и открыт для всех, но зарегистрированные пользователи могут получить привилегии, такие как комментарии, голосование и другие*

Comment: Фраза *Зарегистрируйтесь или войдите* [не помещается в строке](http://image.prntscr.com/image/a2a0ae7c6fd74d7eb8160f641d3ea97b.png). Возможно стоить уменьшить.

Comment: @Alex Зато стало видно, что окно может расширяться в высоту. Т.е. должно быть несложно добавить симметричные отступы по высоте. Может быть надо ему дать возможность и в ширину менять размеры.

Comment: тогда кнопки будут очень длинными

Comment: @Alex ну и отлично: сложнее будет промахнуться :)